# VBA Excel if not executing all lines of code

Tags: excel, vba

Very simple basic code that I have done a million times before, why is it not working?

```
Sheet1.Range("S831") = "QWER"
Sheet1.Range("T831") = "3456"
```

With this code S831 now = QWER but T831 did not update to 3456.  If I put in break points the code will stop at Sheet1.Range("S831") = "QWER" but it will not stop at Sheet1.Range("T831") = "3456"

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Btw, can't hurt to be explicit: `Sheet1.Range("S831").Value = "QWER"`, `Sheet1.Range("T831").Value = "3456"`. Also, if you want a number and not a string, use `= 3456`.

Comment: do you have an `On Error Resume Next`?  Is the sheet protected?  As stated in the comment above with this information we cannot reproduce the problem, so the problem must reside else where in your code.

Comment: If you use F8 to step through the code, what happens? Does it skip to a different line?

Comment: I tried it with .value and that did not help.  I do not have On Error Resume Next.  The sheet is not protected.  I deleted all other code and these two line are all I had.  When stepping through with F8 the second line gets skipped.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try writing it a different way.

```
Worksheets("WorksheetName").range("S831").value = "QWER"
Worksheets("WorksheetName").range("T831").value = "3456"
```

Comment: This did not help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Today it is working, I made no changes...